# How to view child process sorted by aggregate memory usage?

Tags: linux, memory, htop

I'm using top/htop to track memory usage on Linux. I'm seeing a lot of child process consuming a ton of memory, but I'm having trouble finding their parents.

How can I see a process tree view sorted by the overall aggregate memory usage of both the parent and all children? Currently, htop can do both, but they're mutually exclusive views.